# 'FOR XML PATH' for concatenating different row values in one cell by group clause

Tags: sql, concatenation

I have this table:

| Reference | UserName | OrderId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17191.CCF | Mrs Tate | 153122 |
| 17191.CCF | Mrs Tate | 153123 |
| 17191.CCF | Mrs Tate | 153138 |
| 17191.CCF | Mrs Tate | 153149 |
| 17191.CCF | Mrs Tate | 153150 |
| 17191.CCF | Mrs Tate | 153184 |
| 17223.CCF | James Bond | 153301 |
| 17223.CCF | New User | 153361 |

Desired output is:

| Reference | UserName | Orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17191.CCF | Mrs Tate | 153122,153123,153138,153149,153150,153184 |
| 17223.CCF | New User | 153301 |
| 17223.CCF | James Bond | 153361 |

But I am getting the following output

| Reference | UserName | Orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17191.CCF | Mrs Tate | 153122,153123,153138,153149,153150,153184 |
| 17223.CCF | New User | 153301,153361 |
| 17223.CCF | James Bond | 153301,153361 |

I am using this query

```
SELECT
    tbl2.Reference, tbl2.UserName,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(tbl1.OrderId AS varchar (30))
           FROM Table tbl1
           WHERE tbl1.Reference = tbl2.Reference
           FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS Orders
FROM
    Table tbl2
GROUP BY
    tbl2.UserName, tbl2.Reference
```

Can someone please suggest how can I get it right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server, if you are on a newish version you can use `STRING_AGG`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add also a match username in WHERE.

By this you will be matching not only reference column that makes output that you currently having, but also the name. This will fix the duplication.

So the code should look like this.

I haven't tested it just for your reference try it.

```
Select tbl2.Reference, tbl2.UserName,

STUFF((Select ','+cast(tbl1.OrderId as varchar (30))

from Table tbl1
where tbl1.Reference=tbl2.Reference
  AND tbl1.UserName =tbl2.UserName

FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
, 1, 1, '')
as Orders

from Table tbl2

group by tbl2.UserName, tbl2.Reference
```